# Perl gives "gzip: stdout: Broken pipe" error when opening gzipped files, but only if connecting to a DB

Tags: mysql, perl, gzip

Consider the following program, running on a Linux machine, which opens a gzipped input file:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

open (my $fileHandle, "-|", "/bin/zcat $ARGV[0]");
my $ff = <$fileHandle>;
close($fileHandle);
```

That works as expected (it does nothing, but prints no error):

```
$ bar.pl file.gz
$
```

Now, if I use the same code but previously connect to a MySQL database, gzip will complain (you can run the code directly, this is an open DB and the credentials will work):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=hg19;host=genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu";
my $db =  DBI->connect($dsn, 'genomep', 'password');
my $dbResults = $db->prepare("show tables");
my $ret = $dbResults->execute();
$dbResults->finish();
$db->disconnect();

open (my $fileHandle, "-|", "/bin/zcat $ARGV[0]");
my $ff = <$fileHandle>;
close($ff);
```

Running the above gives:

```
$ foo.pl file.gz 

gzip: stdout: Broken pipe
```

This is obviously part of a much more complicated program, but I've managed to trim it down to this silly snippet that reproduces the issue.

What's going on? Why does connecting to a DB affect how gzip behaves? Note that everything seems to work (in the actual program, I do something useful with the gzipped data) but why am I getting that error message?

---

It turns out this behavior is specific to (slightly) older versions of Perl and/or DBI. On the machines where it failed, I have:

- Ubuntu
- Perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
- DBI 1.634
- DBD 4.033
- gzip 1.6

However, on another two machines it did work. These had:

- Ubuntu
- Perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
- DBI 1.640
- DBD 4.033
- gzip 1.6

And

- Arch Linux
- Perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
- DBI 1.642
- DBD 4.050
- gzip 1.10

Comment: Please add `use autodie;` to check for failed syscalls, it reveals more information.

Comment: Both variants work fine for me (on Fedora 29).

Comment: @StephenKitt oh wow. Yes, both work fine for me on my Arch system (`perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0)`) and an Ubuntu system with `perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1)`, but fail on two Ubuntu machines with (`perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1)`. So I guess it was a weird bug that has since been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: (probably) Unrelated: Note also that you are opening `$filehandle`, but closing `$ff`. In the first piece of code, you also have no `my` in front of `$filehandle`.

Comment: No, it's not the Perl version. Fails for me as described above. perl 5.30.0 DBI 1.642 DBD::mysql 4.050 libmariadb-devel 3.1.2 gzip 1.10

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks. I was using a rough and ready version while testing but wanted a clean one here, so I added the stricter code but not carefully enough :) Neither of those is absolutely needed so I sometimes skip them when testing. Fixed now though, thanks.

Comment: @daxim oh. Interesting. I tried it on two other machines, with perl 5.30 (Arch) and perl 5.26 (Ubuntu) and it worked fine there. How do you check the versions of the packages like DBI? Presumably the difference will be there.

Comment: `perl -mDBI -mDBD::mysql -E'say DBI->VERSION; say DBD::mysql->VERSION'`

Comment: @daxim Thanks. I added the versions to my answer below. I'm really surprised that it fails for you with what looks like the same basic versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least here, it appears that the MySQL libraries (probably) are masking (ignoring) SIGPIPE, and that's what you're seeing. Comparing strace outputs, I see a line like this in the MySQL run:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f78bdf16840}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
```

And it turns out you can duplicate the behavior easily w/o MySQL:

```
$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';

open (my $fileHandle, "-|", "/bin/zcat $ARGV[0]");
my $ff = <$fileHandle>;
close($ff);
```

Or, alternatively, you can reset the signal to the default handler to make the message go away, even after connecting to MySQL by setting it to `DEFAULT` instead of `IGNORE`.

This is, by the way, [documented behavior of the MySQL library](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-threaded-clients.html):

> To avoid aborting the program when a connection terminates, MySQL blocks SIGPIPE on the first call to mysql_library_init(), mysql_init(), or mysql_connect().

(It may also depend on the gzip version; maybe some versions of gzip set up signal handlers on init.)

Ultimately, what you're seeing is that if gzip gets a SIGPIPE, it just exits. If it gets an error back from write (because SIGPIPE is ignored), it prints an error message.

Comment: On my Arch (see question for versions) I cannot reproduce it even when using `$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';`. On the machines where it fails, however, `$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';` is indeed sufficient to reproduce. So, given that the gzip versions are the same and I can reproduce without the DBI code, it looks like it is indeed a perl version thing.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the following is happening:
gzip tries to write to the pipe, the program on your side is not reading up to eof, the closes the pipe. Gzip then receives a SIGPIPE, and dies with this error message. Can you confirm that this is taking place?

Comment: But why would it only have an issue when running with the unrelated DBI code and work fine without it?

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out it was a bug in the version I was using which has now been fixed. D'oh!

Comment: Good to know. Could you add some info about the bad version, so that this won't leave others wondering?